I have complex formula in excel and don't know how to sort it out. Can you assist me to fix my below formula?
Here is the time range:
Start Time        End Time
Row L6 9:00:00       Row M6  09:57:15
Row L7 9:57:15       Row M7  10:21:07
Row L8 10:21:07      Row M8  14:48:19
Row L9 14:48:19      Row M9  19:00:00
Row L10 9:00:00      Row M10 13:27:12
Row L11 13:27:12     Row M11 17:37:02
Row L12 17:37:02     Row M12 19:00:00
Row L13 9:00:00      Row M13 09:34:19

Here is the solution that I want:
          START DATE WİTH TİME         END DATE WİTH TİME
Row N6    20.06.2024   9:00:00   Row O6    20.06.2024  09:57:15
Row N7    20.06.2024   9:57:15   Row O7    20.06.2024  10:21:07
Row N8    20.06.2024  10:21:07   Row O8    20.06.2024  14:48:19
Row N9    20.06.2024  14:48:19   Row O9    20.06.2024  19:00:00
Row N10   21.06.2024   9:00:00   Row O10   21.06.2024  13:27:12 
Row N11   21.06.2024  13:27:12   Row O11   21.06.2024  17:37:02
Row N12   21.06.2024  17:37:02   Row O12   21.06.2024  19:00:00 
Row N13   24.06.2024   9:00:00   Row O13   24.06.2024  09:34:19

Start Date is located in cell H5 and has only Date and No Time.
When the time is 19:00:00 in the "End Time" range, you should increment the day by 1 day for the next row day and start from 09:00:00 as mentioned in the Start Time. Saturday and Sunday is weekend. If both dates fall to weekend you should skip 2 days and start always from Monday.
The range to find weekends is:
Row T2:AR2  for the weekday name 
Row T3:AR3  for the weekday date

The weekend is called "HS" and Holiday is "TT".
I tried this formula for the Start Date with Time
=IF(ROW()-ROW($H$5)<=4;TEXT($H$5;"gg.aa.yyyy")&" "&TEXT(INDIRECT("M"&ROW());"ss:dd:nn");
IF(AND(ROW()-ROW($H$5)>=5;ROW()-ROW($H$5)<=8);TEXT(WORKDAY.INTL($H$5;0;"1111100";$T$3:$AR$3)+IF(ROW()-ROW($H$5)=5;1;IF(ROW()-ROW($H$5)=8;4;0));"gg.aa.yyyy")&" "&TEXT(INDIRECT("M"&ROW()-ROW($H$5)+5);"ss:dd:nn");
TEXT(WORKDAY.INTL($H$5;0;"1111100";$T$3:$AR$3)+4;"gg.aa.yyyy")&" "&TEXT($M$20;"ss:dd:nn")))

Everything works in line but when it comes to this point:
21.06.2024 13:27:12
20.06.2024 17:37:02
20.06.2024 19:00:00
24.06.2024 09:34:19

as you can see the dates are not incrementing in line with the date 21.06.2024.
My question is how I can increment the days in line with the previous date.

You need to edit this, two blocks of text is hard to read and have any chance of following the question.

I edited already. You can go through now my question details. Thanks for your assistance in advance.

I wonder whether SCAN would work here:

incr_day_step1 - get increment based on the set time.
incr_day - shift values to apply to the next row.

Since you're using the default (Saturday and Sunday) we could omit the value; but please add your holiday parameter (I have omitted that - for example date_, TEXT(WORKDAY.INTL(start_date, incr_day,,holidays), "dd.mm.yyyy"))
Also, adopt the format string and parameter separator (,) to your regional setting.
Enter the following formula in N6:
=LAMBDA(start_time, end_time, start_date,
    LET(
        incr_day_step1, SCAN(
            0,
            end_time,
            LAMBDA(acc, cur, IF(cur = TIMEVALUE("19:00:00"), acc + 1, acc))
        ),
        incr_day, VSTACK(0, DROP(incr_day_step1, -1)),
        date_, TEXT(WORKDAY.INTL(start_date, incr_day), "dd.mm.yyyy"),
        start_and_end_times_with_date, HSTACK(
            date_ & " " & TEXT(start_time, "hh:mm:ss"),
            date_ & " " & TEXT(end_time, "hh:mm:ss")
        ),
        start_and_end_times_with_date
    )
)(L6:L13, M6:M13, $H$5)



Thanks a lot for your efforts. The problem is solved perfectly. So I need to learn Lambda function very well.

My pleasure! If it is acceptable to you, would you please mark it? What should I do when someone answers my question? - Help Center - Stack Overflow There are many resources, here's a good one: Create Custom LAMBDA Functions in Excel

Now you have written yourself a beautiful ununderstandable formula :-)
In order to understand what it does (and maybe solve your issue) you might try to evaluate your formula step by step, as in the following example:

